# dynamically calling functions exported in node

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node and gradually learning 
I've **app.js** file which is server and **app_functions.js** which holds all my app functions

```
var express = require('express');
var app_functions = require ('./app_functions');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {  
 res.send('Running NODE!');
});

// Ex: when I request http://ip.address:3000/functionOne
app.get('/:method', function (req, res) {
// I want to call function that "method" holds i.e, in this case 'functionOne'
// and that function will reside in app_functions.js
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Server listening');
});
```

I was able to call those functions using global[] when they are in same file.

My **app_functions.js** goes like this

```
exports.functionOne = function functionOne() {
return "functionOne executed";
};

exports.functionTwo = function functionTwo() {
return "functionTwo executed";
};
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you'll probably have to clarify your question in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with it. Just take property of object and then execute it with `()`. Example (also here I check that property is function):

```
var express = require('express');
var app_functions = require('./app_functions');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Running NODE!');
});

// Ex: when I request http://ip.address:3000/functionOne
app.get('/:method', function(req, res) {
    // I want to call function that "method" holds i.e, in this case 'functionOne'
    // and that function will reside in app_functions.js
    if (typeof app_functions[req.params.method] === 'function') {
        app_functions[req.params.method]();
    }
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server listening');
});
```